# Training not working. "Skipping training since max_steps has already saved"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to train an object detector with TensorFlow. I downloaded the pre-trained model `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28`, created my `.pbtxt` file, my train and test records.

I'm using the `model_main.py` which is in TensorFlow/models/research/object-detection

When I try to start training `"python model_main.py --logtostderr model_dir=results/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --model_dir=ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/"`

I get this error:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (.model_fn at 0x125031b00>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
>   W1025 21:53:42.973139 4590234944 model_fn.py:630] Estimator's model_fn (.model_fn at 0x125031b00>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
>   I1025 21:53:42.973598 4590234944 estimator_training.py:186] Not using Distribute Coordinator.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
>   I1025 21:53:42.973851 4590234944 training.py:612] Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
>   INFO:tensorflow:Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
>   I1025 21:53:42.974123 4590234944 training.py:700] Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Skipping training since max_steps has already saved.
>   I1025 21:53:42.978157 4590234944 estimator.py:360] Skipping training since max_steps has already saved.

How can I fix this and start training??

Comment: Any news regarding this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `model_main.py`.

Try `train.py` from `TensorFlow/models/research/object-detection/legacy/` instead.

I used it with the following arguments:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

This worked for me.

Comment: But Im wondering whats the difference between model_main.py and train.py. Maybe someone can tell me??

Answer (score 0):

Does your --model_dir path point to the pretrained model?

--model_dir should point to an 'empty' directory, where your checkpoints will be saved. Path to the pretrained model is defined in the .config file.